# Redirect by browser language in htaccess but only from external urls

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Is it possible to redirect due to browser language but then give users the possibility to change language on the website via navigation menue link?

I tried this but this changes the language of the website according to the browser language but then it is not possible to use the flag/navigation on the website anymore.

```
# language starts with DE
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^de [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /de/ [L,R=301]

# Fallback to default Language (en)
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} !^.*(de|en).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R,L]
```

I thought about the same htaccess code but with the addon: "only for external visitors" so users which are already on this domain, can use the flag/navigation menue to change language and wont redirected anymore by the htaccess.

Is it possible to do that via htaccess?

Thanks!

Comment: Usually you would do this by only rewriting based on browser preference, if no language was “selected” already. But it looks like you have your default language English without any language prefix in the URL - so you can not differentiate between the two cases, “has chosen English deliberately”, and “just visited the site and this was default.” You could check the referrer here, to determine if the visitor came “from the outside” - but the referrer is unreliable, and gets more and more filtered out for privacy reasons these days.

Comment: You could also add a parameter to your language links, like `?force_lang=EN` or something like that - and don’t do a rewrite based on browser prefs, if that parameter is set. But then you would have to drag this parameter along across all your site-internal links.